# Laravel PHP Fitbit API OAUTH - storing and reusing access tokens

Tags: php, oauth, laravel-4, fitbit

I am currently using the fitbit library with a laravel wrapper (see https://github.com/popthestack/fitbitphp).

I am attempting to store the access token once a user authenticates and then subsequently reuse that token instead of having to make a separate request for a new token each time. Is it possible using fitbits oauth 1 implementation to reuse the access tokens or will I need to make a new request using request tokens etc. each time. I apologize in advance, I have a fairly visceral understanding of oauth in the first place but fitbit in particular has been tripping me up. Thanks.

here is the function I have that requests info from fitbit...

```
public function getFitbit() {
    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'oauth_token' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = fitbitOauth::consumer( 'Fitbit' );

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {
        // This was a callback request from fitbit, get the token
        $fb->requestAccessToken(
            $_GET['oauth_token'],
            $_GET['oauth_verifier']
        );

        // Send a request now that we have access token
        $result = json_decode($fb->request('user/-/profile.json'));

        print_r($result);

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get fb authorization
        $token = $fb->requestRequestToken();
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $token->getRequestToken()));

        // return to facebook login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }
}
```

I can run through the above example. Direct a user to the page where they can authenticate their account. This then redirects to a page that displays their info. If I reload the page with the 'token' and 'verifier' set already it fails. I want to be able to save off their token to a DB and reference it in the future.

Comment: The [docs](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+Authentication+in+the+Fitbit+API) seem to indicate that the token can be stored and used with subsequent requests by repeating Step 8 in the OAuth Flow list. The documentation specifically says "Using token credentials, the client makes calls to access Fitbit **resources** on behalf of the user." If the token was valid for only a single call, the doc would (perhaps) say 'resource' rather than 'resources.' Is there a particular part of your code that is tripping you up? If so, will you post it?

Comment: I have added the code I am implementing above

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. Will you explain the specific difficulty you are encountering? What do you expect to happen, what is happening instead, and what error messages do you receive?

Comment: I can run through the above example. Direct a user to the page where they can authenticate their account. This then redirects to a page that displays their info. If I reload the page with the 'token' and 'verifier' set already it fails. I want to be able to save off their token to a DB and reference it in the future.

Comment: When it fails, what happens? Do you get an error message or some other situation that you can describe?

Comment: the only response I get is "failed to request" I'm still looking into exactly where its failing, but I have a feeling I am not grabbing one of the right tokens.